# Android studio onDraw not using updated values

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I currently ran into a problem and have been stuck with this for days.

My goal is to create a marble maze game that used accelerometer sensors. I followed some online resource and was able to get it to work when I just created a BallView that extends View inside my Activity and create this view programmatically.

However, I also need a button on the lower left of the view and I found out that this could not be done inside a custom view. I searched online and came out with a solution to create the MarbleView that extends view with a separate class. I then put this custom view inside my xml file along with my button and inflate them with my activity.

I was able to see the inflated result: my marble maze and a button; however, the problem now is that the view does not update the marble position anymore. I noticed that ball x, y positions are updated in updateBall() but not in onDraw() even though both positions are updated from the same marble model reference. I this there is something to do with the thread but just couldn't figure out how to fix it.

MarbleModel calculates the updated ball positions with acceleration in x, y, z axis. It also generates borders and barriers for view to draw.

My original code that worked without a button:

```
public class MarbleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener2 {

    private Point pixelSize;
    private float xPos, yPos;
    private Bitmap ball;
    private MarbleModel marbleModel;

    private SensorManager sensorManager;

    @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        pixelSize = new Point();
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        display.getSize(pixelSize);

        intent = getIntent();
        gameLocation = intent.getStringExtra(GAME_LOCATION);

        // instantiate MarbleGame with phone screen parameters
        marbleModel = new MarbleModel(pixelSize.x, pixelSize.y);
        xPos = marbleModel.getXPos();
        yPos = marbleModel.getYPos();


        BallView ballView = new BallView(this);
        setContentView(ballView);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            float xAcc = sensorEvent.values[0];
            float yAcc = -sensorEvent.values[1];
            float zAcc = sensorEvent.values[2];
            marbleModel.updateParameters(xAcc, yAcc, zAcc);
            updateBall();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFlushCompleted(Sensor sensor) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
    }

    private void updateBall() {
        xPos = marbleModel.getXPos();
        yPos = marbleModel.getYPos();
    }

    private class BallView extends View {
        public BallView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            Bitmap ballSrc = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
            final int dstWidth = marbleModel.getRadius() * 2;
            final int dstHeight = marbleModel.getRadius() * 2;
            ball = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ballSrc, dstWidth, dstHeight, true);
            getRootView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C9E4CA"));
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(ball, xPos, yPos, null);

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setTextSize((int) (pixelSize.y * 0.05));

            for (Rect border : marbleModel.getBorders()) {
                canvas.drawRect(border, paint);
            }

            for (Rect barrier: marbleModel.getBarriers()) {
                canvas.drawRect(barrier, paint);
            }
            canvas.save();

            canvas.rotate(90);
            canvas.drawText("Roll The Ball To Target",
                    (float) (0.08 * pixelSize.y), -(float) (0.84 * pixelSize.x), paint);
            canvas.restore();

            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

The codes that include a button but ball position couldn't be updated.

(MarbleView is inflated with my MainActivity)

```
public class MarbleView extends View implements SensorEventListener2 {

    private MarbleModel marbleModel;

    private float xPos, yPos;
    private Bitmap ball;

    private float xAcc, yAcc, zAcc = 0f;

    private int width;
    private int height;

    private SensorManager sensorManager;

    public MarbleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null, context);
    }

    public MarbleView(Context context, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, context);
    }

    public MarbleView(Context context, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs, context);
    }

    public MarbleView(Context context, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(attrs, context);
    }

    private void init (AttributeSet attrs, Context context) {
        Bitmap ballSrc = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        width = metrics.widthPixels;
        height = metrics.heightPixels;

        // instantiate MarbleGame with phone screen parameters
        marbleModel = new MarbleModel(width, height);

        xPos = marbleModel.getXPos();
        yPos = marbleModel.getYPos();

        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        final int dstWidth = marbleModel.getRadius() * 2;
        final int dstHeight = marbleModel.getRadius() * 2;
        ball = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ballSrc, dstWidth, dstHeight, true);
        getRootView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C9E4CA"));
    }

    public void updateBall(float xAcc, float yAcc, float zAcc) {
        this.xAcc = xAcc;
        this.yAcc = yAcc;
        this.zAcc = zAcc;
        marbleModel.updateParameters(xAcc, yAcc, zAcc);
        Log.i("updateball", String.valueOf(yAcc));


        xPos = marbleModel.getXPos();
        yPos = marbleModel.getYPos();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Log.i("ondraw", String.valueOf(yAcc));
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball, xPos, yPos, null);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize((int) (height * 0.05));

        for (Rect border : marbleModel.getBorders()) {
            canvas.drawRect(border, paint);
        }

        for (Rect barrier: marbleModel.getBarriers()) {
            canvas.drawRect(barrier, paint);
        }
        canvas.save();

        canvas.rotate(90);
        canvas.drawText("Roll The Ball To Target",
                (float) (0.08 * height), -(float) (0.84 * width), paint);
        canvas.restore();
        invalidate();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            float xAcc = sensorEvent.values[0];
            float yAcc = -sensorEvent.values[1];
            float zAcc = sensorEvent.values[2];
            updateBall(xAcc, yAcc, zAcc);
            Log.i("on sensor changed", String.valueOf(yAcc));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFlushCompleted(Sensor sensor) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
}
```

Appreciate for all the helps!

Comment: Use ballView.invalidate();

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I accidentally found out that it's because I'm instantiating my custom view twice: BallView ballView = new BallView(this) and the other one in my xml file. What I basically do is remove the BallView instantiation and put BallView ballView = findViewbyId(R.id.ball_view). I also modified some of my other codes so that onDraw does not call invalidate().

My codes that worked:

```
public class MarbleActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener2 {

    private MarbleView marbleView;

    private SensorManager sensorManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Point pixelSize = new Point();
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        display.getSize(pixelSize);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_marble2);

        marbleView = findViewById(R.id.marbleView);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);


        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            float xAcc = sensorEvent.values[0];
            float yAcc = -sensorEvent.values[1];
            float zAcc = sensorEvent.values[2];

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    marbleView.updateBall(xAcc, yAcc, zAcc);
                    marbleView.postInvalidate();
                }
            }, 333);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFlushCompleted(Sensor sensor) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
}
```

```
public class MarbleView extends View {

    private MarbleModel marbleModel;

    private float xPos, yPos;
    private Bitmap ball;

    private float xAcc, yAcc, zAcc = 0f;

    private int width;
    private int height;

    public MarbleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null, context);
    }

    public MarbleView(Context context, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, context);
    }

    public MarbleView(Context context, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs, context);
    }

    public MarbleView(Context context, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(attrs, context);
    }

    private void init (AttributeSet attrs, Context context) {
        Bitmap ballSrc = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        width = metrics.widthPixels;
        height = metrics.heightPixels;

        // instantiate MarbleGame with phone screen parameters
        marbleModel = new MarbleModel(width, height);

        xPos = marbleModel.getXPos();
        yPos = marbleModel.getYPos();

        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        final int dstWidth = marbleModel.getRadius() * 2;
        final int dstHeight = marbleModel.getRadius() * 2;
        ball = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ballSrc, dstWidth, dstHeight, true);
        getRootView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C9E4CA"));
    }

    public void updateBall(float xAcc, float yAcc, float zAcc) {
        this.xAcc = xAcc;
        this.yAcc = yAcc;
        this.zAcc = zAcc;
        marbleModel.updateParameters(xAcc, yAcc, zAcc);
        Log.i("updateball", String.valueOf(yAcc));

        xPos = marbleModel.getXPos();
        yPos = marbleModel.getYPos();
        postInvalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Log.i("ondraw", String.valueOf(yAcc));
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball, xPos, yPos, null);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize((int) (height * 0.05));

        canvas.drawText("ver 2.01", 500, 1700, paint);

        for (Rect border : marbleModel.getBorders()) {
            canvas.drawRect(border, paint);
        }

        for (Rect barrier: marbleModel.getBarriers()) {
            canvas.drawRect(barrier, paint);
        }
        canvas.save();

        canvas.rotate(90);
        canvas.drawText("Roll The Ball To Target",
                (float) (0.08 * height), -(float) (0.84 * width), paint);

        canvas.restore();
    }

}
```